# Published Websites in Asp.net iis

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Project was created and published but I have made changes to that project in the controller however the changes aren't been shown, would that be an issue? As for now whatever saved and published that's what being use. I have tried rebuilding the solution as well as delete the temporary .net files and still remain.

**EDIT** 
When I try to publish the website I receive an error thus causing it fail.

**ERROR**

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
```

Error       Copying file packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.1.2.3\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.1.2.3.nupkg to C:\Users\sue-ann.brown\AppData\Local\Temp\WebSitePublish\TWCLIssusingManagementSystem--2062993544\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.1.2.3\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.1.2.3.nupkg failed. The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.  http://localhost/       0

Comment: I think we will need some more detail. Are you saying if you update you controller file and redeploy it is not pushing your changes to IIS?

Comment: yes that's what i'm saying

Comment: Are you using a Web Deploy or how are you pushing your application?

Comment: file system..when i make the changes i just rebuild and then run

Comment: Hey @DerekHackett, can you share with me how I update the applaication so that it would see the changes.

Comment: You should be able to modify the files with VS or another IDE. You will need to make sure that you rebuild the application and redeploy it. Then you should be able to see your changes.

Comment: I have rebuild it and it was build successfully but  when I try to publish it, it fail.

Comment: \Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.1.2.3.nupkg to C:\Users\sue-ann.brown\AppData\Local\Temp\WebSitePublish\TWCLIssusingManagementSystem--2062993544\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\package\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.1.2.3\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.1.2.3.nupkg failed. The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

Comment: when publishing instead of the files created store in the wwwroot folder its saving in my users account

Comment: Are you using application insights? If not go in IIS Modules and make sure you don't have any application insight or telemetry modules process requests on your IIS instance.

Comment: I'm only seeing this ApplicationInsightsWebTracking in t IIS module

Comment: If you disable that it should fix the error you have listed above